# JUnit 5 What happens to test methods with the same @Order(#)?

Tags: junit5

I am using JUnit 5 to test my RESTful application. I have a test class in which test methods are annotated with `@Order(#)`. Any idea what happen when the same order number is used to some test methods? Would they be run in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They won't be executed in parallel. The ordering ensures to sort the test execution order adjacent to each other depending on their value.

```
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class OrderingTest {

  @Test
  void test0() {
    assertEquals(2, 1 + 1);
    System.out.println("Test0");
  }

  @Test
  @Order(1)
  void test1() {
    assertEquals(2, 1 + 1);
    System.out.println("Test1");
  }

  @Test
  @Order(1)
  void test2() {
    assertEquals(2, 1 + 1);
    System.out.println("Test2");
  }

}
```

In this example, `test1` and `test2` have the same order number and the test execution will be: `test1` -> `test2` -> `test0`.

Internally JUnit 5 does the following for ordering:

```
@Override
public void orderMethods(MethodOrdererContext context) {
    context.getMethodDescriptors().sort(comparingInt(OrderAnnotation::getOrder));
}
```

while `.sort()` is from `java.util.List`.

If you want parallel test execution, you can configure this with [JUnit 5 in a different way](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution).

Comment: No, I don't want parallel execution. How does the `context.getMethodDescriptors().sort(comparingInt(OrderAnnotation::getOrder));` end up running `test1` and `test2` in sequence? Doesn't it sort by the `Order(#)` which in this case is the same number `1`, unless it also sorts the method name in lexicographical order?

Comment: `test1` and `test2` have the same order number. What happens if there is the same number multiple times depends on the implementation of `.sort()`.